# Simple Access-Control-Allow-Origin with net module

Tags: node.js

I have two servers one on port 80 which is a normal web server and than one on port 8080 that is a broadcast server that sends a text string with all the updates to show. However the browser gives me a `CORS header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' missing`. And is it any simple way for me to add the header with the net package? The server code looks as following:

Code to create the server:

```
var net = require('net');
var fs = require('fs');
var buffer = require('buffer');
var serverHost = "0.0.0.0";
var serverPort = 8080;
var splitter = require('./splitter.js');

var server = net.createServer(function(target) {

    // Socket errors
    target.on('error', function(error) {
        console.log('Socket error: ', error.message);
    });

    target.on('data', function(data){
        // TODO: Verify the data
        var number = parseInt(data);
        if(!isNaN(number)){
        // Adds the client to the list
            splitter.addClient(target, number);
        }
        else{
            target.write("Match ID is not correctly formatted");
        }
    });
});

// Listening for any problems with the server
server.on('error', function(error) {
  console.log("Error listening to the server!", error.message);
});

server.listen(serverPort, serverHost);
```

splitter code (Add client and send data):

```
var gameids = {1337:[]}

function addClient(client, gameID){
    if(matchExists(gameID)){
        console.log("Client", client.remoteAddress, "begun watching gameID", gameID,"\n");
        var id = gameids[gameID].push(client);
    }
    else{
        client.write("A match with the given ID does not exists");
    }
}

function sendData(data, gameID){
    if(gameids[gameID].length > 0){
        for(i = 0; i < gameids[gameID].length;i++){
            console.log(gameids[gameID][i]);
            if(gameids[gameID][i].writable){
                console.log("Sent data");
                gameids[gameID][i].write(data);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The function send data is called from my main script which just takes the input from another server and then sends that out to all clients watching.

Comment: Sorry, but what is your question in here?

Comment: Please explain in detail what the problem is and where you need help

Comment: Well tired me forgot on sentence. I simply wounder if it is any simple way for me to get in an Access-Control-Allow-Origin with the net package.